# php wont check the second argument even if the first is true

Tags: php

I wrote this:

```
$a[] = "guy";
$b[] = "g";

function login($a1, $b1)
{
  if( user($a1) == true and pass1($b1) == true)
  {
    login2($a1, $b1);
  }
  else
  { 
    echo "error!!!!";
  }
}

function login2($a1, $b1)
{
  if (array_search($_REQUEST["user"],$a1) == array_search($_REQUEST["pass"],$b1))
  {
    echo "you are logged in";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "erorr";
  }
}

function user($user1)
{   
  if(in_array($_REQUEST["user"],$user1))
  {
    echo "gooooooood?";
  }
}

function pass1($pas)
{
  if(in_array($_REQUEST["pass"],$pas))
  {
    echo "goooooooood!!!!!!!!";
  }
  else
  {
    echo "bad";
  }
}

login($a, $b);
```

and I know that `pass()` and `user()` are true because I changed their positions on the function `login()` and every time I did this the first argument was returned as true and it didn't check the second one. Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your user and pass1 functions are not returning an explicit value, so they are implicitly returning the NULL value. As described on [this page in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php) the `NULL` type is converted to `false` when a boolean is expected. So both your user and pass1 functions return `false` every time.

The `&&` and `and` logical operators in PHP use short-circuiting for efficiency (see the first code example on [this page of the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)) so in any `and` statement whose first operand evaluates to `false` it can never be possible for the whole `and` statement to evaluate to `true`, so the second operand (in the case of your code above, the second operand is the call to `pass1($b1)`) is never evaluated because it would be a waste of time to do so.

Which means you're seeing the user function being called, but never the pass1 function.

Answer (score 3):

`user` and `pass1` functions should return `true` or `false`, not echo out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:

```
$a[] = "guy";
$b[] = "g";

function login($a1, $b1)
{
    if( user($a1) == true && pass1($b1) == true)
        login2($a1, $b1);
    else 
    echo "error!!!!";
}

function login2($a1, $b1)
{
    if (array_search($_REQUEST["user"],$a1) == array_search($_REQUEST["pass"],$b1))
        echo "you are logged in";
    else
        echo "erorr";
}

function user($user1)
{

    if(in_array($_REQUEST["user"],$user1))
        echo "gooooooood?";
}


function pass1($pas)
{
    if(in_array($_REQUEST["pass"],$pas))
        echo"goooooooood!!!!!!!!";
    else
        echo "bad";
}
login($a, $b);
```